# Forgot to submit I-94 while leaving USA in 2011

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, overstaying

I visited USA in 2011 on an H-4 visa. I overstayed for two months and then returned to avoid further complications. I forgot to return my I-94 after leaving the US, but have my boarding pass and got stamped at Chennai airport as proof that I returned. It's been six years now and I am planning to visit the USA again.

Will there be any issues if I travel again, this time on a B-2 visa?

Comment: Please use proper grammar and punctuation when posting on the site.

Comment: Did you stay beyond the date shown on the I-94 and were you a minor?

Answer (score 1):

*If* you are granted a B-1/B-2 visa now *then* there is no problem. It's a whole another issue whether you will get one or not. The overstay is the problem, the authorities know when you left from the airline, a real lot of people forgot to return the I-94 piece of paper when it was still paper (now it's electronic), that's not your problem.